# Wrapfigure leaves horizontal space on first line

Tags: spacing, wrapfigure

I don't why this little space between the image and the first word is appearing (as shown in the image below ), how can I delete it ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx,setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{l}{18mm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{world.png} 
\end{wrapfigure} 
\textbf{Bloc world :} ce bloc représente le repère terrestre qui est un repère orthogonale non-mobile. On relie le modèle à la porte \textbf{W} du bloc pour qu'il soit le repère fixe.  \\

\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{l}{17mm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{mechanism.png} 
\end{wrapfigure} 
\textbf{Mechanism configuration :} ce bloc nous permet de configurer les paramètres de gravitation. Comme montré sur la figure XX, la gravité agit sur le sens opposé de l'axe \textbf{y} et sur ce bloc on met : [ 0 -9.80665 0 ].
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a paragraph indent. Remove it by starting the paragraph with \noindent.